# Any home design software similar to The Sims 3?

Tags: 3d-modeling

I tried Sketchup to sketch a home design but I find the controls a bit frustrating. I can sketch 10 times faster in The Sims 3, plus it is nicer to look at. Though the metric system may not be 1:1 ratio to reality but it's close, maybe 15%-20% off but this is a just a sketch, right?

Anyway, is there any software that does home design like The Sims 3? The same ease of use but at a more professional level and a real metric system?

Comment: If you are looking only to do floor layouts, you can use also use Microsoft Visio.

Comment: Thats the only reason i played the sims. hacked it for unlimited money and desinged my dream home.. over and over and over.. I also dont like google sketch.. to professional for a `sketch` Looks like there is a good market for a `SIMS` engine sketch up tool with thousands of items...

Answer (score 5):

**[Sweet Home 3D](http://www.sweethome3d.com/index.jsp)** is an open source tool that I've used quite a few times.  It may not be as easy as the Sims tool, but it's not awful.  And if you're going to use it for anything serious, like a remodeling project, it's really nice to be able to visualize the results.

I used Punch a few years ago, and Sweet Home is not bad in comparison.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I used to use 3d Home Architect years before. Now it's known by a different name, [Punch](http://www.punchsoftware.com/).

[image]

Comment: How does it compare to Chief Architect?